What is the significance of Trump's "250 million Americans"?
The Washington Examiner (and other sources) tells us that Donald Trump has said “I have to begin by saying 250 million Americans are not garbage,”.
Where does this number come from? Current US population estimates are around 335 million, 2020 election results put the Trump vote at around 75 million. It would be an odd way of doing it as it would include people too young to vote, people who didn't vote, and people who had been disqualified from voting, but 250 million would appear to be approximately the number of Americans who did not support Trump.
I'm sure this is not what Trump meant to suggest, or that he intended to leave his own supporters' status undetermined. Has the Trump campaign explained his use of this number?

Fair enough on the close votes. If there had been a statement from the campaign explaining the calculation there would have been a fine on-topic answer, but I wasn't really expecting that.

Gwah! Why do people still try to figure out what Trump means when he says stuff? He doesn't mean anything by this; he simply picked a number that sounded good to his ear and went with it. Trump tries to convey impressions; he never tries to convey meanings. You should take everything Trump says as though he had said "that cloud looks like a duck": a way to direct attention without engaging any underlying substance or content, and likely as not to change the next time he speaks.

While his grasp of any particular meaning to his words is likely tenuous, there is actually some ironic significance to his use of this particular number. It's saying only those who vote for Biden could be considered garbage, which is really the same claim they accuse Biden of making about Trump supporters when taken out of the context of a discussion on some of the garbage his prominent supported said on stage.

@Batman, It's just as possible to say he's saying none are garbage; Biden got ~75 million votes and presumably doesn't consider them garbage.  The US population is ~335 million.  ~335 - ~75 = ~250.  So he's saying the Americans called garbage by Biden aren't.

@Ryan_L Math doesn't check out.

@haxor789 - Of course not, this is the man who thinks (or thought, at least) that Colorado has a border with Mexico.

In 2020, the population of the United States of America was: 331,449,281
In the 2020 presidential election, the citizens of the United States of America cast the following ballots:

Biden/Harris: 81,283,501
Trump/Pence: 74,223,975
Other: ~2m

Subtracting Biden voters from the total population of the USA, we get: 250,165,780
Based on this calculation, it would appear that Trump is (unrealistically) claiming every person in the USA who did not vote for Biden is his supporter, and by saying they are not garbage insinuating someone (Biden) thinks they are.
Mind you this math is not internally consistent, as it would concede Biden did actually get 81 million votes, which Trump has yet to concede if we exclude the times he later said he was being sarcastic. It is also unusual for him to extend such consideration to the sizeable non-citizen population of the USA that helps inflate this number. More evidence this number isn't meant to be thought through seriously.
Another thing that makes this number significant is the implication that those who voted for Biden could be considered garbage. Only the 250m who didn't vote/'support' Biden are exempted in his statement, insinuating some Americans are garbage consistent with what was said on stage at his rally to spark this controversy (plus other remarks about the USA being a "garbage can" and calling Harris supporters "scum" and "absolute garbage") with the amount of Biden voters conspicuously equaling the upper limit on the number of Americans who he would consider garbage. This is really the same type of claim his campaign accuses Biden of making about Trump supporters when taken out of the context of a discussion on some of the garbage his prominent supporters said on stage.

"Another thing that makes this number significant is that he's saying that only those who voted for Biden could be considered garbage." - The last paragraph needs some support. I'm trying, and my mental gymnastics may not be good enough to make the leap into how this is calling Biden supporters garbage. No, Trump didn't schoolyard throw the insult back by saying "No, but you are!". Trump exaggerated Biden's insult to mean anyone who didn't vote Biden is garbage. This makes it appear what Biden said is worse that what he really said. I can't see how its a similar claim.

@DavidS I added some clarification about the implications of the deliberate carve-out. You could quibble about which would be worse, Biden having had more voters would seem to imply Trump actually insulting more Americans, but it's obscured with nonsensical measurements. Also Biden was clearly talking about the garbage from the on-stage supporters to begin with.

Do you think saying "Black Lives Matter" deliberately carves out white lives?

@Ryan_L In a situation like that, I would seek out additional context. Did the people who said it come from a rally where someone said white lives are garbage? If so, I think it's fair to say that may be the intention. In isolation however, no.

@Ryan_L - The most reasonable assumption is that a given Black (or other) person saying that Black lives matter does not hate every White person because of their race; by contrast, the most reasonable assumption given Trump's history is that he does in fact hate everyone whom he believes to oppose him. Prior information should be considered.

@Ryan_L This has been discussed here already.
